# Dynamically adding rows with jQuery with PHP outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm fetching data from a PHP file with jQuery and I want it to be displayed dynamically in a table.
Is there another way of doing this, so that the jQuery itself creates the table rows?
This is my attempt..

Part from the html file:

```
<table id="tejbl">
<tr id="naslov">
<td><h3>NAME</h3></td>
<td><h3>FAT</h3></td>
<td><h3>FIBER</h3></td>
<td><h3>SUGARS</h3></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td id="table_0"></td>
<td id="table_1"></td>
<td id="table_2"></td>
<td id="table_3"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Part from the js file:

```
$('#jedinice_butt').click(function(){
var odabrano = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();

var uneseno = $("#input_jedinica").val();
$('#tablica').show();
//$('#add_button').show();


if(odabrano === "g"){ 
    $.post('name.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {

      $('#table_0').html(data);
    });


    $.post('nutritional_value.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {

      $('#table_1').append( data * (parseFloat(uneseno,10)/100));
    });

    $.post('fiber.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {

        $('#table_2').append(data * (parseFloat(uneseno,10)/100) );
    });

    $.post('sugars.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {

        $('#table_3').append( data * (parseFloat(uneseno,10)/100) );

    });



}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is, that once I click the button again it just adds the values in the same 's and I want it to add in a new row..
So basically how do you dynamically add rows for these outputs
I tried with a few methods with no success I event tried doing it without the 's in the html file so it's generated from the jQuery but I'm doing something wrong apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you could modify the DOM.

First get rid of the

```
<tr>
<td id="table_0"></td>
<td id="table_1"></td>
<td id="table_2"></td>
<td id="table_3"></td>
</tr>
```

You can dynamically add elements to the document. You could do something like this:

```
if(odabrano === "g"){ 

$.getJSON("SCRIPT_URL.php?value="+encodeURI(VALUE_VARIABLE),function(data){

    var ttr = document.createElement("tr");
    var dt = ["fat","fiber","sugar"];
    var ttd = document.createElement("td");
    ttd.innerText=data["name"];
    ttr.appendChild(ttd);
    for(var i=0,l=dt.length;i<l;i++){
        var ttd = document.createElement("td");
        ttd.innerText = data[dt[i]] * (parseFloat(uneseno,10)/100);
        ttr.appendChild(ttd);
    }
    $("#tejbl").append(ttr);

});

}
```

A note for the php-script:
Send the data like this:

```
$results = array();
$results["name"]=$NAME_YOU_JUST_GOT_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
$results["fat"]=$FAT_YOU_JUST_GOT_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
$results["fiber"]=$FIBER_YOU_JUST_GOT_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
$results["sugar"]=$SUGAR_YOU_JUST_GOT_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
//Send it to the client in json format:
echo(json_encode($results));
```

Comment: I get this error:

[12:24:54.296] TypeError: w is null @ http://localhost/tust/index2.html:141

Comment: Oh, my bad...
I have updated the answer, take a look add the post requests to sugars and fibers, i had used the wrong id, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but I get the same error even with the edited code :S

Comment: I read the documentation and it says:
Returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first matching element.

So what could be the reason it returns NULL (why can't it find a match) ?

Comment: Hmmm, strange...
Try to change the line `$.tdf.addedData=0` to `$.tdf.addedData=1`.
If that does not work, could you try to combine the 4 php scripts?

Comment: When I set $.tdf.addedData=1 I get the first error and another one:
[12:52:57.659] ReferenceError: $tdf is not defined
btw the only reason I'm using multiple php files for every item is because I don't know how to target specific variables in php..
If the php outputs multiple echos with values how do I get specific ones and not all of them with data? :S

Comment: Ok, I tried setting it up from just one php file (fiber.php) just to see if I'm going to get the same value in all the fields, but nothing.. Same error, w is null.

Comment: Try to put the results into an array, maybe like
`$results["name”]=$resulting_name` and the print it in json format:
`echo(json_encode($results));`.
On the client side use $.getJSON("URL",callback(data){});
Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.
I did as you said and nothing is displayed. I think I'm doing something wrong with the POST or GET in the php file.
This is my php file now:
http://pastebin.com/vQVWFMJp
The value variable that's being passed is a string from a link:
    var value = $('a').text();

Comment: No, that was my bad...
Change `$.getJSON("SCRIPT_URL.php",function(data){` to
`$.getJSON("SCRIPT_URL.php?value="+encodeURI(VALUE_VARIABLE),function(data){`

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm already getting annoying or something...
Now it creates the td's in a row, but they're empty..
I tried to change the $value = $_GET['value']; in the php script to: $value = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; but that didn't work either. I don't quite understand this JSON, I should watch some tutorials probably

Comment: Maybe I need to decode json in php before the value is being used for a db query search?